# Adjacently positioned dropdowns seem to be entangled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a dropdown component using Object Oriented Javascript.

Later I instantiated 2 instances of this dropdown component and rendered them adjacent to each other.

The problem I am currently facing is: when the down-arrow is clicked and items in the 1st dropdown are rendered then the position of the 2nd dropdown changes.

JS Bin : https://jsbin.com/ruluzarixe/3/edit?html,output

I am unable to understand why this is happening. Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

```js
function Dropdown() {
  this.id = '';
  this.items = [];

  this.settings = {
    isRendered: false,
    isListOpen: false
  };

  this.init = function(componentId) {
    this.id = componentId;
    this.cacheDOM();
  };

  this.cacheDOM = function() {
    this.$el = $('#' + this.id);

    if (this.settings.isRendered) {
      this.$input = this.$el.find('input');
      this.$dropbox = this.$el.find('div');
      this.$dropdownicon = this.$el.find('span');
      this.$ul = this.$el.find('ul');
    }

    this.template = `<div id='` + this.id + `'>
                      <div class='dropbox'><input /><span class='material-icons'>expand_more</span></div>
                      <ul style='display: none'>
                        {{#items}}
                        <li><span>{{.}}</span></li>
                        {{/items}}
             </ul>
           </div>`;
  };

  this.populateItems = function(items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.render();
  };

  this.applyStyles = function() {

    var elStyle = {
      'display': 'inline-block',
      'position': 'relative'
    };

    var dropboxStyle = {
      'display': 'inline-flex',
      'border': '1px solid #9DD9D2'
    };

    var inputStyle = {
      'font': 'inherit',
      'padding': '3px',
      'border': 'none'
    };

    var inputFocusStyle = {
      'border': 'none',
      'outline': 'none'
    };

    var dropdownIconStyle = {
      'background-color': '',
      'color': '#17BEBB'
    };

    var dropdownIconHoverStyle = {
      'cursor': 'default',
      'background-color': '#9DD9D2',
      'color': 'white'
    };

    this.$el.css(elStyle);
    this.$dropbox.css(dropboxStyle);
    this.$input.css(inputStyle);
    this.$input.on('focus', function() {
      $(this).css(inputFocusStyle);
    });
    this.$dropdownicon
      .css(dropdownIconStyle)
      .on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).css(dropdownIconHoverStyle);
      })
      .on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).css(dropdownIconStyle);
      });
  };

  this.bindEvents = function() {
    this.$dropdownicon.on('click', this.toggleList.bind(this));
  }

  this.toggleList = function() {
    var listOpenStyle = {
      'display': 'block',
      'list-style-type': 'none',
      'border': '1px solid #9DD9D2',
      'margin': '0'
    }

    var listClosedStyle = {
      'display': 'none'
    }

    this.settings.isListOpen = !this.settings.isListOpen;

    if (this.settings.isListOpen)
      this.$ul.css(listOpenStyle);
    else
      this.$ul.css(listClosedStyle);
  };

  this.render = function() {
    var data = {
      items: this.items
    };
    this.$el.replaceWith(Mustache.render(this.template, data));
    this.settings.isRendered = true;
    this.cacheDOM();
    this.applyStyles();
    this.bindEvents();
  };

};

var dropdown = new Dropdown();
dropdown.init('city');
dropdown.populateItems(['Munich', 'Oslo', 'Havana']);
dropdown.render();

var dropdown2 = new Dropdown();
dropdown2.init('city2');
dropdown2.populateItems(['Los Angeles', 'Miami', 'Edinburg']);
dropdown2.render();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <span id='city'></span>
  <span id='city2'></span>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position`, `left` and `right` values to your `ul`s

```js
function Dropdown() {
  this.id = '';
  this.items = [];

  this.settings = {
    isRendered: false,
    isListOpen: false
  };

  this.init = function(componentId) {
    this.id = componentId;
    this.cacheDOM();
  };

  this.cacheDOM = function() {
    this.$el = $('#' + this.id);

    if (this.settings.isRendered) {
      this.$input = this.$el.find('input');
      this.$dropbox = this.$el.find('div');
      this.$dropdownicon = this.$el.find('span');
      this.$ul = this.$el.find('ul');
    }

    this.template = `<div id='` + this.id + `'>
                      <div class='dropbox'><input /><span class='material-icons'>expand_more</span></div>
                      <ul style='display: none'>
                        {{#items}}
                        <li><span>{{.}}</span></li>
                        {{/items}}
             </ul>
           </div>`;
  };

  this.populateItems = function(items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.render();
  };

  this.applyStyles = function() {

    var elStyle = {
      'display': 'inline-block',
      'position': 'relative'
    };

    var dropboxStyle = {
      'display': 'inline-flex',
      'border': '1px solid #9DD9D2'
    };

    var inputStyle = {
      'font': 'inherit',
      'padding': '3px',
      'border': 'none'
    };

    var inputFocusStyle = {
      'border': 'none',
      'outline': 'none'
    };

    var dropdownIconStyle = {
      'background-color': '',
      'color': '#17BEBB'
    };

    var dropdownIconHoverStyle = {
      'cursor': 'default',
      'background-color': '#9DD9D2',
      'color': 'white'
    };

    this.$el.css(elStyle);
    this.$dropbox.css(dropboxStyle);
    this.$input.css(inputStyle);
    this.$input.on('focus', function() {
      $(this).css(inputFocusStyle);
    });
    this.$dropdownicon
      .css(dropdownIconStyle)
      .on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).css(dropdownIconHoverStyle);
      })
      .on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).css(dropdownIconStyle);
      });
  };

  this.bindEvents = function() {
    this.$dropdownicon.on('click', this.toggleList.bind(this));
  }

  this.toggleList = function() {
    var listOpenStyle = {
      'display': 'block',
      'list-style-type': 'none',
      'border': '1px solid #9DD9D2',
      'margin': '0',
      'position' : 'absolute',
      'left': '0',
      'right': '0'
    }

    var listClosedStyle = {
      'display': 'none'
    }

    this.settings.isListOpen = !this.settings.isListOpen;

    if (this.settings.isListOpen)
      this.$ul.css(listOpenStyle);
    else
      this.$ul.css(listClosedStyle);
  };

  this.render = function() {
    var data = {
      items: this.items
    };
    this.$el.replaceWith(Mustache.render(this.template, data));
    this.settings.isRendered = true;
    this.cacheDOM();
    this.applyStyles();
    this.bindEvents();
  };

};

var dropdown = new Dropdown();
dropdown.init('city');
dropdown.populateItems(['Munich', 'Oslo', 'Havana']);
dropdown.render();

var dropdown2 = new Dropdown();
dropdown2.init('city2');
dropdown2.populateItems(['Los Angeles', 'Miami', 'Edinburg']);
dropdown2.render();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <span id='city'></span>
  <span id='city2'></span>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `position` property of the two divs (`#city`, `#city2`) to `absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

use `vertical-align: top;` as below in your code

```
var elStyle = {
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'position': 'relative',
            'vertical-align': 'top'
            };
```

Comment: Adding "vertical-align: top" also solves the issue. But I am accepting the answer by @HerrSerker. Thanks for the answer.